# How to make a dynamic accordion menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have the following menu structure. I have 3 problems with it.

```js
$('.parent ul').hide();

var current_parent;
$(document).delegate('.parent', 'click', (function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  if(current_parent !== undefined) {
    current_parent.find('ul').slideUp();
  }
  
  current_parent = $this;

  // Check if the element is visble or not
  if(!$this.find('ul').is(':visible')) {
    $this.find('ul').slideDown();
  } else {
    $this.find('ul').slideUp();
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="parent">menu item1
    <ul>
      <li class="child">Sub menu item1</li>
      <li class="child parent">Sub menu item2
        <ul>
          <li class="child">Sub-sub menu item1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="parent">menu item2
    <ul>
      <li class="child">Sub menu item3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. When you click on `menu item 1` the `Sub-sub menu item1` is also
   opened. How can this be prefented?;
2. When you click on `Sub menu item2` the `menu item1` is also closed. How can this be prefented?.
3. How can I make this more dynamic so that when I add deeper menu items the menu still works but without having to add things like: `$('ul ul ul').slideDown();` etc.?

Could anyone help me with these problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+dropdown+menu+with+jQuery

Comment: @BobBrown Ofcourse googled first before I asked here

Comment: Can't you give the <ul> an id?

Comment: @The_Monster yes ofcourse you can :P

Answer (score -1):

You can create a drop drop down menu with jquery

I have given individual HTML, CSS and JQuery code, use it and try to understand it.

There is an outer `<div id="navigation"> and inside it their is an``now in it every`

`is main menu item and``in every`

`is sub menu item. Furthermore you can create sub menu in sub menu also by creating``in`

`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("li").click(function () {
  var x = $(this).children("a:first").attr("href");
  if (x != undefined)
   window.location.href = x;
 });

 $("#nav li").hover(function () {
  $(this).find("ul:first").css({
   visibility: "visible",
   display: "none",
  }).slideDown(400);
 }, function () {
  $(this).find("ul:first").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
 });

});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Calibri, Verdana;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: white;
}

a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation {
 height: 40px;
}

#nav {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 10px 0px 0px -5px;
 padding: 0px;
 display: none;
}

#nav li {
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
 border: 0px solid transparent;
 border-right-width: 1px;
 border-right-color: gray;
 background-color: #6397CB;
}

#nav li ul li {
 width: 145px;
 height: 22px;
 padding: 10px 0px 8px 10px;
 border: 0px solid transparent;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-top-color: gray;
}

#nav li ul li ul {
 position: relative;
 top: -40px;
 margin-left: 145px;
 color: white;
}

#nav li ul li ul li {
 border: 0px solid transparent;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-left-color: gray;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-top-color: gray;
}

#nav li:hover {
 background-color: lightgray;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#nav li ul li:hover {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">

 <ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">My Name</a></li>
  <li>About U
   <ul>
    <li>How U?
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Your Extras</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Howz U?</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: This not relevant to what the op is asking, You gave him a great option but it doesnt fix the issue he's dealing with